# Sum of squares related with integers

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_{19}$ be positive integers satisfying $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{19}x_i=2020$ and $x_i \geq 2$ for $i=1,2,...,19$.

Find the smallest value of $$P=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{19} x_i^2.$$

I've thought it was an easy question at the first place by using a very common result
$$P \geq \dfrac{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{19} x_i\right)^2}{19}=\dfrac{2020^2}{19}.$$

However, the equality does not occur since $x_i$ are positive integers. I'm struggling with finding another strategy for this problem! Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum value will be if all $x_i$ are ,,as equal as they can be*'', so if all are around 106. Say $k$ of them are exactly 106 and the rest of them 107, so we have $$106k+107(19-k)=2020$$
Now calculate $k$ and you are done.

---

This * is because of this inequality $$(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2\geq x^2+y^2$$ if $x>y$.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still cannot figure out what is the relationship between $*$ and your inequality $(x+1)^2+(y-1)^2 \geq x^2 +y^2$.

Comment: If two numbers are more than 1 apart, then you can reduce one of them for 1 and second one enlarge for 1. Say you have $8^2+5^2$ this you can reduce to $7^2+6^2$...

Comment: I got it. This method is nice. Thanks a lot.